# How to set default option in select when we use Object populate select option from Reactive form?

Tags: angular, forms, web, angular-reactive-forms

I've one pop up form in which there is select option, you can think of various option of food dishes, now I have following code to select the option and submit. But currently, after update when I reopen the pop up form, the select field is blank. In db it is storing perfect option.

component.ts:

```
dishes: any[] = [];
updateFoodDishesForm: UntypedFormGroup;
selectForUpdate: any;

constructor(){
this.updateFoodDishesForm = new UntypedFormGroup({
           // Food dishes is an object in backend which has multiple field such as id, name 
            foodDishes: new UntypedFormControl('')
        });
}

ngOnInit() {
        // Loading food dishes option for select element
        this.dishesService.getAllFoodDishesDetails().subscribe((dishes ) => {
            this.dishes = dishes;
        });
    // we are setting selectForUpdate before calling the modal pop up
      this.selectForUpdate = dishesService.getCurrentFoodDetails();
    }

 openModalForm() {
        let foodUpdateFormData = {
            foodDishes: this.selectForUpdate.foodDishes
        };
    this.updateFoodDishesForm.patchValue(foodUpdateFormData);
    }
```

template:

```html
 <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="control-label requiredField">
                            {{ 'Select Food dishes:' | translate }}
                            <span class="asteriskField"> *</span>
                        </label>
                        <select id="foodDishes" formControlName="foodDishes" class="form-control">
                            <option value="" disabled [selected] >Select Option</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let indianDish of dishes" [ngValue]="dish">{{ indianDish.name }} ({{indianDish.id }})</option>
                          </select>
         </div>
```